# Bevel goes in wrong direction and creates distortion?

Tags: modeling, workflow, edges, bevel

I am trying to bevel the edge of my circle. When I select only one edge it causes the Bevel to be inverted and stretched over the other two edges:

[image]

When I try to do it on the half circle:

[image]

My first Idea was to change the value of the actual profile but it didn't help either. Using *Inset* to remove the Ngon I get the following result:

[image]

The File:
[image]

**Q:** Why is the bevel operation acting that way in this case and how to bevel the edges properly?

Comment: I'd suggest selecting the edge loop around the opening, as the entire circle need to be selected, the pictures indicate that the selection was not the loop needed to get the bevel you want.

Comment: Even with the hole circle selected it still produces the wrong result. Added Image on main Post:

Comment: Would you mind sharing the file, removing all not related objects to reduce the size is recommended and much appreciated. You can use [Blend-Exchange](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/), you will need to copy the address of the question for the service, as it is limited for questions and answers here.

Comment: You have huge ngons in your mesh. Bevelling an ngon is practically the same as trying to add a loopcut to an ngon. The outcome is unpredictable. Try to use "Inset" on the big big ngons and then try to bevel again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some of the face normals in your mesh are flipped. One method to display the face normals in Blender 2.8x is to use its new "Face Orientation" overlay.

[image: Display Face Orientation]

Consistent face normals are very important, not only for the bevelling process. Amongst others they determine in which direction the vertices move when subdividing or bevelling a mesh.

Recalculating normals with <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>N</kbd> doesn't always work. It fails most notoriously on meshes with ngons or on non-manifold meshes. In this cases you have to do the clean-up manually.

Switch to Face Select mode (<kbd>3</kbd>), then select the inner face of the intrusion, then hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>+</kbd> on your Numbad until all the connected faces are selected. Then use "Operator Search" (F3 or Space, depending on your keymap settings), type "flip normals" and hit enter.

[image: Flip Normals]

Bevelling your mesh should work now correctly.

Other reasons why bevelling might produce inconsistent results are

- Double Vertices
- Unapplied Scale
- N-gons

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Blender Stack Exchange!

I just downloaded the file and inset the ngon like in your first image. I got the same results as you did, but recalculating the vertex normals fixed the issue.

This can be done by selecting everything in edit mode and pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>

Comment: I was going to say, looks like a normals problem.