# Problem/Glitch with Matcap and a normal map

Tags: objects, 3d-view, normal-map, matcaps

I have a a high poly object that looks normal in the studio viewport (on the right) but when i select any kind of matcap(on the left), the object has this weird effect. At first i didnt think much of it, but now when i tried to bake the normals onto a low poly mesh the normal map also had that weird effect.
Does anyone know how to resolve this or at least what is causing it? It is only happening whit this object.[image: matcap/studio][image: normal map]

Comment: Have you checked your mesh for [flipped normals](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/172871/23985)?

Comment: Yes i did, i forgot to mention that, i checked for flipped normals