# Weird Redering Image

Tags: rendering

I trying to rendering image with low focal length camera (CCTV like) and I getting weird result. Some materials are appearing ahead while they should appearing behind others. My engine is Eevee.

Here is my preview (solid):
[image]

And here is my result:
[image]

Any sugestions?

Comment: It's a downloaded model, I assume? Did you check for [flipped normals](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/172871/23985)?

Comment: @metaphor_set Yes, it doesn't work. It feels weird because I have no problem with Cycles engine.

Comment: Look at the modifiers on the objects, perhaps there are some that are disabled during rendering?

Comment: Are you using alpha blend with materials?

Comment: @ZargulTheWizard Yes! Thanks. Do you know why it doesn't impact on Cycles engine?

Comment: @lonz praise the Lord! :-) I posted it as an answer so this will no longer be in the unanswered section. One thing I didn’t mention...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comment echo: This is because of alpha blend in EEVEE materials. Because EEVEE uses rasterizing (fakes physical effects like transparency using formulas), it can be suspect to flaw in odd situations. Alpha blend  tries to implement full transparency function, but mainly experiences problems where it is trying to sort faces within the same object. Which one is in front? Treating something as partially transparent when you’re faking is very tricky to do.

Cycles does not have this problem because it uses ray tracing. It simulates the behavior of real light, and traces out every single pixel in the image. This is why cycles takes more computing power, but produces more realistic results.

If you have to use EEVEE, one good halfway solution is alpha hashed. Alpha hast is basically alpha clip, but with random threshold for each pixel, each sample. Alpha clip means a pixel is either fully transparent or fully opaque, depending on the threshold level. What then happens in alpha hashed with partially transparent materials is kind of a fuzzy mixture that looks better with each successive EEVEE sample.