# How to avoid half-spheres being black on ambient oclusion map when they are joined to the model at his bottom?

Tags: mesh, texturing, baking, ambient-occlusion

I made a model of a small robot for my animation. It has three spheres cut in half attached to the bottom (For now i just cut them and joined with the rest of the mesh, without interior faces). I am saving my models as FBX always and texturing them in Quixel Mixer. The problem is, when i try to bake Ambient Oclusion map for this one, every time bottom spheres are whole black. Of course i understand that it somehow means that they are behind bottom face and light can't get there... but i saw a lot of models with elements on theit bottom and they weren't black on AO. How to fix it?

[image]
[image: here is an example of one of AO maps][image: here is one of the first AO baked for this model with some other black areas (fixed now) but focus on black circles]
[image: Here is how it looks in Quixel Mixer after adding AO][image: Here is how it looks inside the mesh]
[image: bottom of a model]

Comment: Have you checked your meshes for [flipped normals](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/172871/23985) before exporting to fbx?

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know i can display flipped normals in that way, you probably just gave me a solution for most of my problems.

Comment: You're welcome. Blender's UI hides a lot of little helpers. It's really worth exploring because they are all useful in some cases.