# Why is the bevel acting strangely?

Tags: modeling

[image]

[image]

Basically a Boolean operation + some vertex cleanup. What's causing this weird geometry when i bevel the edges? is it the unbalanced number of vertices on the Boolean object and the main mesh?

Comment: Try to apply the scale. Ctrl+A > Apply transforms.

Comment: @brockmann didnt fix it, i'll upload the file shortly

Comment: maybe recalculate the normals or make sure you don't have any inner faces

Comment: @moonboots yea the normals were the issue, completely missed it. thanks

Comment: @brockmann yep it does

Comment: Cool, explanation over here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/172871 is spot on IMHO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flipped normals can make the bevel fail. Select all in *Edit* mode and press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>N</kbd> to recalculate the normals.